# Postgres trigger function with param and OLD/NEW called from another trigger function

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Trying to create trigger which is supposed to use NEW and OLD and also accept table name as param, but always getting error:

Comment: `log_update()` is the trigger function, `function_update()` is not. So `TG_ARGV[0]` has no meaning. More to the point `function_update()` needs to be a regular function that has a declared argument e.g. ` `function_update(table_name varchar)`. Also you will not have access to `NEW` and OLD` in it. It would be easier to just include the UPDATE statement from  `function_update()` in `log_update()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, could you advise is there anyway this palce can be simplified:

stmt :=
            'update '
         ||  table_name
         || ' set status = :1,'
         || ' where id = :2';

    EXECUTE v_stmt
                  USING NEW.status ,
                        OLD.id;

As it can have way more columns to update in the future

Comment: You need to add back the functions you are working with otherwise your question and comment have no context and make no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly call a trigger function from SQL or PL/pgSQL. So this line is wrong

```
EXECUTE function_update(table_name );
```

for three reasons:

- `EXECUTE` takes a string containing an SQL function as argument. So PostgreSQL wants to call your function and execute the result as an SQL statement. You mean `PERFORM function_update(table_name);`, but that is also wrong for the following reasons.
- You supply an argument to the function, but you defined it without parameters. This causes the error message.
- You are trying to call a trigger function in an SQL statement. That will always fail.

You shouldn't have defined `function_update` as trigger function, but as normal function that can be called from SQL.